# pthread.h No file or directory compilation error using MinGW in command prompt

Tags: c, stanford-nlp, word-embedding

I am implementing glove word embeddings from this link https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/tree/master/src. While compiling glove.py I am facing this error.

```
**D:\MinGW\bin>gcc glove.c -o glove.exe
glove.c:30:21: fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pthread.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.**
```

I am using Windows 10.I installed pthreads win32 library but my OS is 64 bit and again i faced similar problem.I downloaded minGW-w64 and compiled.This time I am getting this error
[image: pthread issue]

How to solve this error

Comment: Use `gcc glove.c -lpthread -o glove.exe`, also you need to install the package  `mingw32-pthreads-w32` or 64 depending of the architecture.

Comment: @KeineLust I am getting same error.Do I need to install anything additionally in MinGW?I have downloaded basic developer kit,c ,c++ and msys only

Comment: What do you use the C++ tag for a C program?

Comment: @KeineLust I have instaled mingw32-pthreads-win32 but my OS is 64 bit so I am getting same error.I have downloaded mingw-w64 installer.But I am not sure how to compile it.It contains mingw32 folders too.